# Форматирование денежной суммы с цифрового представления в строковое с использованием разных валют

Tags: java, javax.money

Добрый день!

Существует ли готовое решение по конвертации цифрового денежнего представления в строковое для разных валют на русском языке?

Например:

123.4 = сто двадцать три рубля 40 копеек

123.4 = сто двадцать три евро 40 евроцентов

123.4 = сто двадцать три доллара и 40 центов

123.4 = сто двадцать три франка и 40 су

И также для других валют.

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449055/190934

Comment: не нашел в этом вопросе ответа, так как по мимо цифрого представления прописью, необходимо поддержка разных валют и их строковое представление (доллар, гривна, крона, тенге) и соответствующее изменение падежей

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовая библиотека для перевода суммы в строку [moneytostr-russian](https://github.com/javadev/moneytostr-russian).

Подключение:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javadev</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneytostr</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Использование:

```
MoneyToStr moneyToStr = new MoneyToStr(MoneyToStr.Currency.RUR, MoneyToStr.Language.RUS, MoneyToStr.Pennies.NUMBER);
moneyToStr.convert(123.4D)

// сто двадцать три рубля 40 копеек
```

Comment: рассматривал данную библиотеку, но к сожалению она не подходит, так как нет поддержки других языков, кроме руского, украинского и английского, а также поддержки других валют, кроме рубля, гривны, доллара и евро
есть возможность добавить кастомное значения для валюты, но ищу решение, которое уже содержит в себе большинство валют и языков для них